# Xamarin.Forms: Navigation to a page failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am in my first app using Xamarin and I'm finding difficulty in page navigation. Researched in various places and getting success the first time I used the navigation.

But when I added a button the page builder that need to navigate is called but does not open any page. When I click the button I've ever worked (list according to the print below) it goes, but I notice that clicking device Windows Phone hardware button click the first failure ie it should be another page in the stack. I do not know how to solve, because in this second button works perfectly but the first can not solve and not find what may be the problem.

Use the Windows Phone project to test and use the Visual Studio 2015 Community.

**Buttons screenshot:**

[image]

**MainViewModel.cs where do the command of setting to draw navigation via click on the buttons:**

```
private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

public MainViewModel()
{
        RescisaoCommand = new Command(NavigateToRescisao);
        FGTSCommand = new Command(NavigateToFGTS);

        _navigationService = DependencyService.Get<INavigationService>();
}

private async void NavigateToRescisao()
{
        await _navigationService.NavigateToRescisao();
}

private async void NavigateToFGTS()
{
        await _navigationService.NavigateToFGTS();
}
```

**App.cs Constructor:**

```
public App()
{
     DependencyService.Register<IMessageService, MessageService>();
     DependencyService.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();

     // The root page of your application
     MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView());
}
```

**INavigationService.cs Interface:**

```
public interface INavigationService
{
    Task NavigateToRescisao();
    Task NavigateToFGTS();
}
```

**NavigationService.cs:**

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    public async Task NavigateToRescisao()
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new RescisaoView());
    }

    public async Task NavigateToFGTS()
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new FGTSView());
    }
}
```

**FGTSViewModel.cs constructor (works):**

```
public FGTSViewModel()
{
     CalculateFgtsCommand = new Command(x => { ShowResult(); });

     _messageService = DependencyService.Get<IMessageService>();
     //_navigationService = DependencyService.Get<INavigationService>();
}
```

**RescisaoViewModel.cs constructor (not work):**

```
 public RescisaoViewModel()
 {
       Reasons = new List<string>();
       TypesOfNotice = new List<string>();

       Reasons.Add("Pedido de demissão");
       Reasons.Add("Justa causa");
       Reasons.Add("Sem justa causa");
       Reasons.Add("Término de contrato de experiência");

       TypesOfNotice.Add("Trabalhado");
       TypesOfNotice.Add("Indenizado");

       //_navigationService = DependencyService.Get<INavigationService>();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He managed to solve the problem.I checked my bindings and they were incomplete names.

The problem was that there was an error description to help me, I believe this can serve other people.